# Compare two documents, find similar sentences

Tags: linux, grep, diff, comparison

I am trying to compare two text files documents (40 pages+) that seem to have similar sentences scattered around them. I would like to detect these similarities somehow. The first idea that popped into my head was to look up any three consecutive words that exist in both files (case insensitive). Sadly, I am not a Linux master. Is there some script that would identify these for me?

Comment: Are the sentences *similar* or *identical*? *Identical* sentences is easy: Convert \n to space, and . to \n (using `tr`) to get each sentence on a line of its own. Then `sort file1 file2 | uniq -d` finds identical sentences. *Similar* is much more difficult (and it's not even clear what kind of similarity is meant, so some examples would help).

Comment: Extract three consecutive words: Again convert \n to space, then `sgrep -o '%r\n' '" ".." ".." ".." "'` to output three words separated by one space. Like above, `sort` and `uniq` to find sequences using the same three words.

Comment: @dirkt thank you for your response. Sorry my explanation was not completely clear. I meant the script should detect any identical three words in the same sequence between the two files and return these three words (each result in a line /n). I understand what you said about the steps of converting the lines and dots to spaces, but I am not sure how to write the syntax (I am not usually a big Linux user). It particularly confuses me on where to put "file1" and "file2" in the sgrep command. I hope I won't be asking for too much if I asked for the actual syntax :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to extract three consecutive words for every sentence:

Assume the two files are called `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`. Convert every end-of-line to a space using `tr`, then extract lines with three consecutive words in each using [sgrep](https://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/jjaakkol/sgrep.html) (you probably need to install this, many distributions offer it as a package):

```
cat file1.txt | tr '[\n]' ' ' | sgrep -o '%r\n' '" "_." ".." "._" "' > file1.words
cat file2.txt | tr '[\n]' ' ' | sgrep -o '%r\n' '" "_." ".." "._" "' > file2.words
```

Make sure to insert a space or newline before the first and after the last word in `file1.txt` or `file2.txt`, or it won't work for the first resp. last three words. This keeps punctuation and makes it part of a word, you can get rid of punctuation by inserting an additional

```
... | tr -d '[,.;:()]' | ...
```

after the first `tr` (the `|` character builds "pipes" between commands, so the next command uses output from the previous one).

Next, find repetitions of the three words:

```
sort file1.words file2.words | uniq -d
```

This will print out any set of three words that occurs multiple times, be it in the same file, or both in `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`. You'll need to manually inspect every occurence (using search in a text editor) to find out which, but you'll want to do that anyway to judge the similarity.

This is still a very crude approximation of similarity match, but I don't know of any handy command-line tools that offer something like [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) measurements on pairs of lines.